# SO Retag Request: dbixclass to dbix-class

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

The module is named `DBIx::Class`, and the distribution files and repos are named `DBIx-Class`, both of which look like two words to Google, so by all rights the tag standards say we should rename. `dbix-class` currently has no questions on SO, simply because everyone has been good about using the tag that already exists. `dbixclass` has 45 questions, which I think is enough to make a mass retag appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I agree.

I tried to add a proposed tag synonym [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=dbix-class&sort=info&pagesize=50), but it failed because [dbixclass] is used more than [dbix-class].  I support the hyphenated form of class names as the canonical form of the respective tag.